# Hive transformation NULL pointer exception

Tags: hive

I have value in source system where any negative decimal value is stored as 10.35- (Minus sign after value)

When I wanted to store this hive, I want I want negative sign to be before value like -10.35.

```
CASE WHEN substring(trim(colName), -1) = '-' THEN
abs(regexp_replace(colName, '[^0-9.]', ''))*-1 ELSE 
abs(regexp_replace(colName, '[^0-9.]', '')) END
```

The above transformation is working perfect, but throwing NULL pointer exception if column contains blank or empty value.

How can I handle this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need abs() function:

```
select CASE WHEN trim('10.35-') rlike('-$') 
                THEN regexp_replace('10.35-', '[^0-9.]', '')*-1 
                ELSE regexp_replace('10.35-', '[^0-9.]', '') 
        END
```

returns `-10.35`

In case of empty value it will return `''` - empty value. Use cast( as double) if you need null in this case:

```
select CASE WHEN '' rlike('-$') 
                THEN regexp_replace('', '[^0-9.]', '') *-1 
            ELSE cast(regexp_replace('', '[^0-9.]', '') as double) 
        END
```

Returns `null`

But if you want to use `abs()` then `cast(as double)` first, it will convert empty string to null and abs will work without exception returning `null` :

```
select abs(cast ('' as double))
```

returns `null`